# Chainlink Keeper not running upkeep

Tags: chainlink

I'm trying to use the Chainlink Keeper network and wrote a contract that implements `KeeperCompatibleInterface`. However, even if I explicitly set `upkeepNeeded = true`, the keeper network still does not run the upkeep. I have made sure the contract is adequately funded. What could be the problem?

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
    function checkUpkeep(bytes calldata checkData)
        external
        override
        returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory performData)
    {
        return _checkUpkeep(checkData);
    }

    function _checkUpkeep(bytes memory checkData)
        internal
        view
        returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory performData)
    {
        bool jobCanRun = (block.timestamp > _jobStartTime) &&
            (block.timestamp < _expirationTime);
        bool jobShouldRun = (block.timestamp.sub(_jobLastRun)) >=
            _jobIntervalSeconds;
        upkeepNeeded = jobCanRun && jobShouldRun;
        performData = checkData;
        // debug
        upkeepNeeded = true;
    }

    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata performData) external override {
        (bool upkeepNeeded, ) = _checkUpkeep("0");
        require(upkeepNeeded, "Should not upkeep");
        emit AtroposUpkeepPerformed();
        _jobLastRun = block.timestamp;
    }
```

Comment: Can you add a link to the registered upKeep associated with this contract?

Comment: I face the same issue. I check the link balance and the condition is just fine but It doesn't work. Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Fund your upKeep contract with more LINK tokens.

The upKeep requires a minimum balance to even start running based on gas costs, the LINK token price, and how much gas your upkeep takes. I'd begin with at least 50 Link tokens.

Please keep in mind that Chainlink Keepers are in beta right now so all of this will be better documented after the beta ends and user feedback is aggregated.