# Chainlink keeper not running performUpkeep, yet checkUpkeep returns true

Tags: chainlink

Like the title says, it seems all the conditions for a keeper to run performUpkeep have been met, yet it is not being called.

Here is the upkeep link: https://keepers.chain.link/kovan/upkeeps/413

Here is the contract: https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x969F42c92A6aeBD925982CCc1C943185B6D0E357#code

Here is the relevant code:

```
function checkUpkeep(bytes calldata checkData) external view override returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory performData) {
        upkeepNeeded = shouldHarvest();

        // We don't use the checkData
        // checkData was defined when the Upkeep was registered
        performData = checkData;
    }

    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata performData) external override {
        harvest();

        // We don't use the performData
        // performData is generated by the Keeper's call to your `checkUpkeep` function
        performData;
    }

    function shouldHarvest() internal view returns (bool) {
        bool hasPendingOutput = IMasterChef(chef).pendingBall(poolId, address(this)) > harvestThreshold;
        bool harvestCondition = hasPendingOutput && !paused();
        return harvestCondition;
    }
```

Things I have tried:

- Increasing the gas limit, by making a new upkeep: https://keepers.chain.link/kovan/upkeeps/416
- Using a contract without the "view" modifier on checkUpkeep (like the interface in @chainlink/contract npm package: https://keepers.chain.link/kovan/upkeeps/414

I used Remix to query checkUpkeep on the https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x969F42c92A6aeBD925982CCc1C943185B6D0E357#code to see that it is returning true.

Comment: Here's a relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68218018/chainlink-keeper-not-running-upkeep

Comment: Could you please share the signature of the harvest method?

Comment: Nevermind, just saw the source code at Etherscan :)

Comment: I face the same issue. I check the link balance and the condition is just fine but It doesn't work. Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

It seems the issue is in the harvest function:

`function harvest() public whenNotPaused onlyEOA`

The `onlyEOA` modifier could be preventing the function from being called since Keepers likely calls it from a smart contract.